# illegal use of outer join operator error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tried to convert old ANSI MS sql join syntax to new join syntax but number of rows in the results not matching.I have tried *querydesigner-verify sql syntax* option and  received *illegal use of outer join operator* error.

```
Source sql
select TableA.DATA1,TableB.DATA2  
from TableA, TableB  
where TableB.Sequence =* TableA.Sequence  
  and TableB.CSequence =* TableA.CSequence
```

I have tried the below sql but resulting rows count is not matching

```
Select TableA.DATA1,TableB.DATA2  
from TableA  
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB 
  ON TableA.SEQUENCE = TableB.SEQUENCE 
 and TableA.CSequence = TableB.CSequence
```

Comment: focus on the second query.  What are the expected vs actual results?

Comment: =* is the old syntax for a RIGHT JOIN, not a left join. Either flip the tables around and keep a left join or use a right join here, not a left join.

Comment: I get the exact same plan for both versions  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JGjJ.png

Comment: @SeanLange because they have written `TableB.Sequence =* TableA.Sequence  and TableB.CSequence =* TableA.CSequence` not `TableA.Sequence =* TableB.Sequence  and TableA.CSequence =* TableB.CSequence` they are fine. That is Table B right join A - which is the same as A left join B.

Comment: @chandralal can you give us a sample data set in A: B where this is happening (perhaps run both find the record(s) being omitted and use them as your example?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query from OP is the same one.

`*` indicates the side to be preserved and it's tableA side, so it's equivalent of `TableA left join TableB`

And here is the test:
[image]